# How to insert multi-line comment in Doxygen code examples

Tags: c++, comments, doxygen

I am trying to include a code example which contains a multi-line comment in Doxygen documentation. The problem is that the C++ preprocessor interprets the `*/` as the end of my Doxygen comment and therefore the syntax of the file is broken.

For example:

```
/*! \brief My Doxygen comment.
 *
 * \code
 * myFunction() /* Some multi-line comment */
 * \endcode
 */
```

I already tried the suggestion which works for JavaDoc comments: encode the slash using HTML entities like this:

```
* \code
* myFunction() /* Some multi-line comment *&#47;
* \endcode
```

but this doesn't work (I guess because Doxygen does not replace HTML entities within code sections).

So the question is: is it possible to include multi-line comments in code example and how can it be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use different comment styles.

Instead of what you have, use:

```
/// \brief My Doxygen comment.
/// 
/// \code
/// myFunction() /* Some multi-line comment */
/// \endcode
///
```

The `///` is the same as `/*!` and marks a doxygen portion. The pre-processor will treat each line as a single line comment.